# Why are emails not commonly hashed when stored in db?

Tags: php, email, hash

With almost weekly news about databases being pilfered I am wondering why only passwords are hashed and not emails too? To be clear, I mean hashed with a static salt, which is stored somewhere other than the database.

Obviously, it's just one step among many. But as part of a multi-faceted security setup (ie - PDO, not rolling your own hasher, rate limiting, etc etc) why is it not more common to hash the email? Regarding logins (+ password reminder emails, etc) you could simply do a regular compare. Surely user emails should be treated more respectfully?

I have read a number of similar questions on SO / sister sites but am really unconvinced as to how this is not an idea that should be adopted more frequently?

Comment: How do you plan on sending an email that has been hashed? I think you are missing one critical step, you should be looking up what hash is, it will answer the question for you.

Comment: See also: [Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948322)

Comment: ^^^ that there is your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Because you usually need to be able to *read* the email address at a later date. Not just verify its value.

Passwords are not used for anything but validation so you don't need to know it's actual value so long as you have a way to validate that value. Comparing hashes allows you to do that.

Emails addresses are actually *used* for something. Like, *sending emails*. You can't do that unless you can actually read the email address.

Comment: *Aye, true John.* However, they can always encode/decode it, but that's just way too much work for nothing really.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly. Unless for some reason those email addresses are senstivie, and that's a reach, encrypting them is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I agree John. I was thinking of the same sorts a few weeks ago and glad that I talked it over with a mutual friend of ours and made me "see the light". I quickly abandoned the idea. A mere *1 minute of thought* saved me *hours of work* ;-)

Comment: I think I was using the incorrect terminology (hashing vs encryption) - my mistake. Regardless, I am not convinced. To answer the question of how to send an email - you do not send an email unless the one entered (ie, on my email form) matches the encrypted entry in the db (ie via password_hash). As to the question of "why bother" - because I believe that emails are hugely private and sensitive bits of info that should be secured.